# How do I access a property of one particular instance of a model class across all instances of my UITableViewCell class?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm currently building an iOS app which, in one of its views, contains a UICollectionView inside each row of a UITableView so that the user can scroll the entire view down but can also scroll each individual row to the right. It looks exactly like the Spotify home page, for instance. The purpose of the app is also to play sound files; when you click on one of these Collection View cells, the sound plays.

To do this, I created a custom UITableViewCell class. The UIViewController that controls this view references that class with an IBOutlet to the UITableView that contains those custom table view cells, and the custom UITableViewCell class references the UICollectionView inside it with an IBOutlet to that UICollectionView. Then I have another custom class for these UICollectionViewCells that only makes sense to use inside my custom UITableViewCell class.

The problem is that I want to know, globally, if any sounds are playing. However, each instance of the custom UITableViewCell class creates *its own* instance of the model where the property isAnythingPlaying exists, so accessing this property tells me only if any sound files inside the current UITableViewCell is playing. For clarity:

```
class Model {

    // (other properties would normally be here)

    var isAnythingPlaying: Bool = false

    // (other functions would normally be here)

    func getIsAnythingPlaying() {
    /*
    The problem with this method is that it will update a property (isAnythingPlaying)
    that needs to contain the same value no matter which cell of the table view 
    (CustomTableViewCell) is accessing it.

    This is just pseudocode for the real method, which works as intended.
    */

        if (somethingIsPlaying) {
            isAnythingPlaying = true
        }

        else {
            isAnythingPlaying = false
        }
    }
}
```

Then my CustomTableViewCell class looks like:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell! {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var customModel = Model!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

        customModel = Model()

    // (other functions would normally be here)

    }
}

extension CustomTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, 
  UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    ***************************************************************
    // at this point the value model.isAnythingPlaying will expectedly be different
    // for each instance of the UITableViewCell. If anything is playing within that
    // particular cell (row), it will be true; otherwise, false.
    ***************************************************************

}
```

Is there something I can do to enable all the CustomTableViewCell objects to access the same isAnythingPlaying variable? I considered putting it in a text file in the bundle and having the code switch the text file from "true" to false" but that seemed too ridiculous to actually try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `static` property which you would set directly on `Model` via `Model.isAnythingPlaying = true`.  Declaring a variable as static puts that property onto the class itself and ensures there will only ever be one value for the property.  If you want to reference a static variable from within an instance of a Model, you can reference the class name as I did above or use the `Self` keyword, note the capital 'S'.

```
class Model {
    // static property that every instance can read/write by using Self.isAnythingPlaying
    // any object outside of the Model class can access the same value by
    // accessing the property on the class ex.  
    // if Model.isAnythingPlaying { 
    // }
    static var isAnythingPlaying: Bool = false

    func getIsAnythingPlaying() {
        return Self.isAnythingPlaying
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need a singleton. Just to have a bool variable is extremely simple:

```
class MyModel {
    var isAnythingPlaying: Bool = false

    static let shared: MyModel = {
        let instance = MyModel()
        return instance
    }()
}
```

To reference from your view class:

```
if MyModel.shared.isAnythingPlaying {
    // do something
}
```

In this simple implementation, your logic to set the isAnythingPlaying variable to true or false can happen anywhere.

In practice you need a little more logic, possibly keeping a list of ids of objects that are playing, since you don't want a player that stops to set the variable to false if something else is playing. If you took this approach, you could give the singleton a computed variable:

```
var currentlyPlayingIDs: [Int] = []
var isAnythingPlaying {
    get {
        return !self.currentlyPlayingIDs.isEmpty
    }
}
```

Then when an item starts playing, it could update the singleton this way:

```
MyModel.shared.currentlyPlayingIDs.append(self.id)
```

and similarly remove its ID when it stops playing.

There's probably some need for notification handling and posting for unrelated objects to share that something changed.

If any of this action happens off the main UI thread you'll need to make sure that the changes are thread-safe, which is way beyond the scope of the question but just thought I'd mention it.

Here's the Swift singleton pattern Apple documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/managing_a_shared_resource_using_a_singleton